# Copy first four characters from one column to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the first four characters from column B (starting from B2) to column I (starting from I2).

This code shows

> error "1004"

```vb
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("B2:B100").Cells
    If Cell.Value = "" Then
        Cell.Value = Left(Cell.Offset(0, -7).Value, 4)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How is a offset of -7 in columns possibel, if you are in column 2?

Comment: Put this in column I and drag down: =left(b2,4). Then copy paste special values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your columns mixed up. Loop column B, and write into column I (which is an offset of 7, not -7).

```
If Cell.Value <> "" Then
   Cell.Offset(,7).Value = Left(Cell.Value, 4)
End If
```